# on degree zero elements in adelic groups

Tags: algebraic-groups, adeles, algebraic-number-theory

Let $G$ a split connected reductive group and $G(\mathbb{A})$ his points in the ring of adeles.

We have a degree map $G(\mathbb{A})\rightarrow X_{*}(Z)$ where $Z$ is the center of $G$.

Let $G(\mathbb{A})^{1}$ the degree zero elements and take an element $\gamma\in G(\mathbb{A})$

Do we have an isomorphism between $G_{\gamma}(\mathbb{A})^{1}\backslash G(\mathbb{A})^{1}$ and
$G_{\gamma}(\mathbb{A})\backslash G(\mathbb{A})$  where $G_{\gamma}$ is the centralizer of $\gamma$?

Comment: If the restriction of the degree map to the center surjects, then I'd think the answer is yes! e.g. Gl(n) and sl(n).